# Can I have auto-properties in a COM Interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, refactoring

I currently have an interface for a COM component that is something like this:

```
[ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("aa950e58-7c6e-4818-8fc9-adecbc7a8f14")]
    public interface MyIObjects
    {
        void set_price(float rx);
        void set_size(long rx);

        float get_price();
        long get_size();
    }
```

Now is there a simple shortcut that might reduce two lines of the following to one line

```
            void set_price(float rx);
            float get_price();
```

I know in classes I can do something like this

```
int Price { get; set; }
```

but will this work in an interface ?

Comment: You mean a Visual Studio feature/shortcut?

Comment: Yes a visual studio feature or a macro (but C# doesnt have macros)

Comment: I think [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp50/Refactorings__Convert_Method_to_Property.html) has something along that lines, but I can't comment for sure.

Comment: Oh, if your question is only "can I have auto-properties in an interface", then the answer is "yes". Thought you were looking for a keyboard/function shortcut helper in Visual Studio that would do it automatically (like Refactor -> Extract Method) and update all references/usages to use standard get/set syntax rather than invoking the non-existent methods.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I believe his question is "Can I have auto-proerties in a ***COM*** Interface", is the answer still "Yes" in that case?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not too sure about that. The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx) for "Example COM Class" states: "**Properties**, methods, and events must be public" which seems to imply they are supported. EDIT: and here are two other pages which state the same thing, but I can't find anything _explicit_: [Exposing .NET Framework Components to COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx) , [Qualifying .NET Types for Interoperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fcfby2t.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM only cares about interfaces, not about their implementation.  You already declare a property with a syntax that resembles an auto-property definition.

```
[ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IMyObjects
{
    float price { get; set; }
    int size { get; set; }
}
```

How you implement the property is entirely up to you.  And yes, using an auto-property in the class that implements the interface is fine.

```
[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MyObjects : IMyObjects {
    public float price { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the *long* type as it appears in COM type libraries or native code is the same as the *int* type in C#.

---

Here is what the IDL definition of the interface would be (assuming inside the namespace `CSDllCOMServer`)

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(AA950E58-7C6E-4818-8FC9-ADECBC7A8F14),
  version(1.0),
  oleautomation,
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "CSDllCOMServer.MyIObjects")

]
interface MyIObjects : IUnknown {
    [propget]
    HRESULT _stdcall price([out, retval] single* pRetVal);
    [propput]
    HRESULT _stdcall price([in] single pRetVal);
    [propget]
    HRESULT _stdcall size([out, retval] long* pRetVal);
    [propput]
    HRESULT _stdcall size([in] long pRetVal);
};
```

Comment: You covered really well what I was going to go over in my answer (you just beat me to it) I added in the IDL definition for the sample interface in to your answer (I was going to put in my own answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare properties in interfaces just fine!

Comment: I believe his question is "Can I have auto-proerties in a ***COM*** Interface", does the fact that this will be used for COM and possibly consumed by non .NET programs affect the answer? (I am not saying it does, I just think that factor needs clarification)

Comment: How would the implementation of this interface look like if I used an auto-property ?